# Reading a variable-sized line and splitting its content into separate lines with text

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed, awk

I have a file with the header (first line) with a variable length; and it comes as:

```
"One"|"Two"|"Three"
```

or

```
"One"|"Two"|"Three"|...|"One Hundred"
```

and want to get do a loop that transforms it into a new file:

```
"Hello One!"
"Hello Two!"
"Hello Three! ..."
"Hello One Hundred!"
```

What should I do? Use awk? sed?

I couldn't find a solution without fixing the size.

My OS is `Linux-RedHat-RHEL-6`.

Comment: Are the double quotes part of your actual data?

Comment: Yes, but they as well could come without it.

Comment: Need there be a special solution for `...`? The second example include it inside the string.

Comment: ... it just means that it continues to "Four"|"Five"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash: read the pipe-separated words into an array

```
IFS='|' read -ra words < <(head -n 1 file)
printf "Hello %s!\n" "${words[@]}"
```

awk: iterate over the words in the line.

```
awk -F'|' 'NR == 1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print "Hello " $i "!"; exit}' file
```

and a sed:

```
sed -e 2Q -e 's/\([^|]\+\)/Hello \1!/g' -e 's/[|]/\n/g' file
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, will accept it later cause I still can't :D

Comment: Why not use `head` with the awk approach as well to keep things simple?

Comment: `sed` example does not do the quotation correctly. It need to be `[^|"]` in the first expression.

Answer (score 2):

Here a simple solution with two sed calls (assumes every line is quoted):

```
sed -n '1s#"|"#"\n"#gp' file | sed 's#"\(.*\)"#"Hello \1!"#'
```

First sed command replaces "|" with newlines. Second adds the texts and exclamation mark.

If there are no `|` inside the data and surrounding `"` are optional, you can also use (shoud be faster):

```
head -1 file | tr \| \\n | sed 's#"\?\(.*\)"\?#"Hello \1!"#'
```

Comment: This actually matches the desired output in the OP post though you could do without the first sed (and faster): `tr \| \\n | sed...`

Comment: @don_crissti  yes, but your suggestion fails if `|` is inside the string. My solution at least handle some of these special cases. If there are no `|` inside the strings, why is there the quotation?

Comment: @don_crissti ok, I extend my answer.